# Gettig user input and storing it/using it c#

Tags: c#, variables, input

I've been learning for a little over a month now in c# and I have a little problem.

I want to get user input and store it into variables then do some operations with it, and then get an answer, but I can't even get it to print anything nor let me write. Could someone please tell me what I did wrong and how to fix it?

```
{
    Console.Write("Enter Mass1 ");
    string Mass1 = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter Lil Numbers ");
    int LilNum = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter Mass2 ");
    int Mass2 = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter Lil Numbers ");
    int LilNum2 = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter Distance between Mass1 & 2 ");
    int distance = Console.ReadLine();
}
    int Mass3 = Mass/Mass2;

}
```

Comment: See [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse).

Comment: Or `double.TryParse`. If you are going to do division (particularly of physical quantities like mass), you probably aren't going to be satisfied with integers. I'm curious, though, what is (/are) "Lil Numbers"?

Comment: Its like those numbers when you square a number I make them another variable to make it simpler

Answer (score 0):

I have rewrote your program and added inline comments which will help you understand what you did wrong..

```
Console.Write("Enter Mass1 ");
int Mass1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

// Console.ReadLine() method returns the `string` 
// hence you need to parse it to specific type before assigning it
Console.Write("Enter Lil Numbers ");
int LilNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

// same here
Console.Write("Enter Mass2 ");
int Mass2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

// same here
Console.Write("Enter Lil Numbers ");
int LilNum2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

// same here
Console.Write("Enter Distance between Mass1 & 2 ");
int distance = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

// You are using `Mass` which is not present
// `Mass1` was `string` type on which you can not do division
int Mass3 = Mass1 / Mass2;
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be receiving an error when trying to read directly from the `Console` to an `int`, as the [`Console.ReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.7.2) function returns a `string`.

That aside, you'll want to utilize the `TryParse` static functions of the type you want to convert the string to.

For example, using your code, we can loop while the user input is invalid, like if they enter `"x"` for a number, using the `TryParse` function:

```
string val;
int Mass1, LilNum, Mass2, LilNum2, distance;

do {
    Console.Write("Enter Mass1 ");
    val = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!int.TryParse(val, out Mass1));

do {
    Console.Write("Enter Lil Numbers ");
    val = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!int.TryParse(val, out LilNum));

do {
    Console.Write("Enter Mass2 ");
    val = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!int.TryParse(val, out Mass2));

do {
    Console.Write("Enter Lil Numbers ");
    val = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!int.TryParse(val, out LilNum2));

do {
    Console.Write("Enter Distance between Mass1 & 2 ");
    val = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!int.TryParse(val, out distance));
```

Or, you could put this loop in a function, like so:

```
public static void ParseUserInput(string msg, out int outval)
{
    string val;
    do {
        Console.Write(msg);
        val = Console.ReadLine();
    } while (!int.TryParse(val, out outval));
}

public static void Main()
{
    int Mass1, LilNum, Mass2, LilNum2, distance;
    ParseUserInput("Enter Mass1 ", out Mass1);
    ParseUserInput("Enter Lil Numbers ", out LilNum);
    ParseUserInput("Enter Mass2 ", out Mass2);
    ParseUserInput("Enter Lil Numbers ", out LilNum2);
    ParseUserInput("Enter Distance between Mass1 & 2 ", out distance);
    Console.WriteLine("Mass 3: {0}", Mass1/Mass2);
}
```

This code utilizes the [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) function, but there is also a `TryParse` for all of the other primitive numeric types, like `long`, `double`, etc. The `TryParse` function will return `false` if the string is an invalid numeric value, and `true` if the parse succeeded; if the parse succeeds, the value will be put in the `out` value.

You can also use the `Parse` function of the type you are converting, like [`int.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2), however, you'll need to take into account that the `Parse` function will throw an `Exception` if the parsing failed, for example:

```
try {
    Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
    int val = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}", val);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("There was an error parsing the number: {0}", ex);
}
```

Just remember you cannot trust user input and must validate the value's entered are within the ranges that are valid for your program. As an example, your `Mass2` cannot be a `0` value since you divide `Mass1` into it for `Mass3` (`int Mass3 = Mass1/Mass2;`). Additionally, you'd likely want to cast the `int` values to a `float` for your `Mass3`, e.g. `float Mass3 = (float)Mass1/Mass2;`

I hope that can help.